# How do I save JavaScript variables even upon reloading or closing the tab?

Tags: javascript, variables, local-storage

I've already seen and tried

```
var someVarName = "value";
localStorage.setItem("someVarKey", someVarName);
var someVarName = localStorage.getItem("someVarKey");
```

But I don't understand how to calculate with that. So say I have a variable, score, and I want it to be raised to the power of 1.1 every time the function frame() runs.

```
var score = 2;

function frame() {
  score = Math.pow(score, 1.1);
  Console.log(score.toFixed(2));
}
setInterval(frame, 25);
```

How would I set this up so that even when you reload the page, it would stay at whatever it was before? Even when I've tried setting up a local storage, I can't get it to access that upon reloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to first determine if your score has already been stored or not. Right now it seems that you keep overwriting the `'score'` item in the storage back to `2` every time you load the page.

So retrieve the `'score'` item from the storage and check if the value is `null`. That would mean that there is no value stored and one should be created.

In your `frame` function update the score item in the storage after every calculation. This way the storage value is always updated to the most current calculation and continues at said value whenever you reload the page.

```
function saveScore(score) {
  localStorage.setItem('score', score);
}

let score = localStorage.getItem('score');
if (score === null) {
  score = 2;
  saveScore(score);
}

function frame() {
  score = Math.pow(score, 1.1);
  saveScore(score);
  console.log(score.toFixed(2));
}

setInterval(frame, 25);
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! I have just one more question--how would I encorporate a function to clear that local data? `localStorage.removeItem('score')` doesn't do the trick and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Well it should work. But my guess is that as long as the `setInterval` is running the score will continue to save. So you could stop the interval before you clear the local data.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var score = 2;
localStorage.removeItem("score");
var oldScore = localStorage.getItem("score");
if (oldScore) {
  score = parseFloat(oldScore);
}

function frame() {
  score = Math.pow(score, 1.1);
  localStorage.setItem("score", score);
  console.log(score.toFixed(2));
}

setInterval(frame, 25);
```